# Shall I rely on traditional method for GET/POST request or other libraries (Android)

Tags: android, json, okhttp

I'm a beginner in android development, working on an app. I wanted to know that shall I use the traditional method for GET/POST request(i.e **URLConnection,HttpClient**) or should i go with Third party libraries such as **OkHttp** or **Picasso**. Which approach shall i use please provide guidance . Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the response but i think google can only give the solution, not guide you. That's why i asked here.

Comment: ok then you should check [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi ManishNegi, Welcome to the site. The question is rather opinion based and can be somewhat broad in scope and difficult to answer. The FAQ identifies the proper format most often used in the site. Basically direct and specific Q&A which can be answered with a correct solution. This is more of a discussion question. The good news is that you can change the content and title to conform to a solid question. Hopefully others will comment on how you can make this a valid SO question. Of  course people could also just give their opinion. I'd stick with the Android standard libraries personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **not** use HttpClient, it's deprecated and removed in Marshmallow.

URLConnection is good but it doesn't provide any help in reading the response, i.e. you have to read the stream yourself which can quickly be a pain. Also you have to make sure your call is asynchronous, that means adding more and more code... not perfect.

So, you're left with OkHttp or Volley. These are "low level" networking libraries, which only help you make requests and read responses. They do it very well though, go ahead and read their doc.

Besides those, you may use other libs for more specific uses. If you need to make some calls to a well-formed REST API, I suggest using Retrofit based on OkHttp.

If you need to retrieve images, Picasso is perfect at that (and also leverages OkHttp). I guess the other guys on the "market" are good too (Glide, Fresco, etc) but I haven't used those.

Find some articles that compare the performance and ease of use of all these libs. You should never add a lib without minimum evaluation.

And finally... https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices

Cheers.

Comment: Thanx i'm using OkHttp and Picasso. I just wanted to know whether my approach is correct or not . Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Surly you do it with traditional method for GET/POST. I am giving you an example for that. 
For that you have to create a class that extends with AsyncTask

```
public class getData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("Write you url here");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

// Here you can write your method - GET or POST

```
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(response);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("tag");
                    Log.e("", "TAG : - " + id);
                    Category category = new Category(id);
                    albumsList.add(category);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("", "Home Exception : " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        pDialog.dismiss();

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                getList_category().setAdapter(new MenuAdapter(getActivity(), albumsList, 0));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You have to call this class in onCreate method or anywhere you want to call it.

```
new getData().execute();
```

Like above mention.

Happy code and Happy to Help....

Comment: thanx for the response but I think it's easy with OkHttp what do you think?

Comment: All things are easy, you have to just do it. I'll help you at every point. I'll show you way now, try to modified it according to you.